# pyLucene - How to use BM25 similarity instead of tf-idf

Tags: lucene, tf-idf, pylucene

As I understand pyLucene now offers BM25 similarity also. I am using pyLucene - 4.10.1, but can't find any example as to how to use BM25 instead of tf-idf. Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Try using setSimilarity of IndexSearcher to setup the retrieval model.

```
import lucene

from java.nio.file import Paths
from org.apache.lucene.store import SimpleFSDirectory
from org.apache.lucene.index import DirectoryReader
from org.apache.lucene.search import IndexSearcher
from org.apache.lucene.search.similarities import BM25Similarity


lucene.initVM(vmargs=['-Djava.awt.headless=true'])
directory = SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR))
searcher = IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory))

searcher.setSimilarity(BM25Similarity())
```